# Why doesn't Firefox OSX VoiceOver fire Focus & Blur events?

Tags: macos, firefox, voiceover

Firefox doesn't seem to fire focus or blur events when mac `VO+Right` or `VO+Left` is pressed.  I can see the VoiceOver focus indication but no event is logging.  I had tried `$(elm).focus(); $(elm).focusin();` and also tried to use bind to set the events.

I know FireFox lacks VoiceOver support, at least for the 2.0 features like live regions, but I really didn't expect to not be able to detect the focus.

Is there a different way I should be doing this in Firefox OSX?